# How can I redirect www without moving to the homepage?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

Well I'm using this code to redirect the domain and ip:

```
RewriteEngine On

rewritecond %{http_host} ^www.lucrebem.com.br [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://lucrebem.com.br/$1 [r=301,nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)['"$] /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^216\.245\.194\.194
RewriteRule (.*) http://lucrebem.com.br/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What it does is removing the www from the url, but the problem is, if an user hits `www.mysite.com/thecategory/thearticle`, he won't be redirected to `mysite.com/thecategory/thearticle`, he will be redirected to `mysite.com/index.php`

That's not what I'm trying to achieve and I believe this is affecting my rankings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it this way and you can combine you rules into one instead of separate rules.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.lucrebem\.com\.br [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^216\.245\.194\.194
RewriteRule ^ http://lucrebem.com.br%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go Buddy, this should remove the `www` and redirect it to domain + slugs:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    Redirect permanent / http://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I fixed it:

```
### Makes www Redirect to non-www without redirecting to index page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.lucrebem\.com\.br
RewriteRule (.*) http://lucrebem.com.br/$1 [R=301,L]
```

And here is a Bonus for people who wants to redirect the Ip too:

```
#Redirects IP, working fine, don't change anything below
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^216\.245\.194\.194
RewriteRule (.*) http://lucrebem.com.br/$1 [R=301,L]
```

:)